# how to send emails when there is new events created.?

Tags: php, email

I need some suggestions for sending an email to the content editors of my project(i.e, my admin Admins).

First let me explain my project..

my project is mainly for events(fests) that are occurred in all over my country.

here when user is submitted a new events details into my database, an approval mail will be send to all the Content Editors of my project. if the content editor accept the details then only the events are published in my website.

Here is the main problem i have more than 10 content editors. so, how can i send event approval mails to all content editors..

i know there is a mail package in php and i already used that for sending mail to one person only.

can i use that package in my project..?
or is there any other solutions are available for this problem.?

thank you.

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: [It’s pretty simple](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

Comment: If you have a solution that sends one email, why not wrap a foreach loop around it to send multiple emails?

Comment: Ya I did that..
but the problem is it takes more than 2min to sending the all mails to my content editors...
i am asking is there any another package which can execute quickly then PHP mailer..?
here i am sending the mails after submit the data data..

Answer (score 3):

why not just add everyone's email to the `to` field of the php mail command

```
$subject = "Changes";
$message = "Some email message";
mail('user1@example.com,user2@example.com,user3@example.com', $subject, $message);
```

[php mail](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

Answer (score 2):

Use a while loop to continue sending the emails is how I would do it. Make sure to use the PHP [**mail()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function as well. Store all the emails of the people in a database and run a query which will return their emails. From there, use the while loop to get all the emails and put a mail function inside the while loop.

Comment: thanks for the solution..
i already tried your solutions before...
While sending mails to all users it takes more than 2min..
Here I am using the PHP Mailer Package..
Is there any another package which can be able to send all mails to users in a less time..??

Comment: 2 minutes depending on how many emails you're sending isn't too bad. Honestly, I do not know of a way that is faster.

Comment: I am sending 40 mails..
I looped those 40 mail id's for sending Event Approvals..
This happen when user submit the data..
that means the user must wait for 2 min to sending those mails.

Comment: Not necessarily, the mail() function simply posts the email to a server, it does not send out the email, the server does. Maybe wait for a better solution.